# JSF h:inputText disabled by JavaScript but values not being sent to managed bean

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-1.2

i have one one code where am using java-script in JSF1.2 jsp page,
On check box m disabling Text box n its working fine. 
But when there is value from DB(example _ "15" in text box),and if i uncheck check box_
m calling JS code which is disabling plus assigning "0.0" to text box, when i click on save its saving "15" in DB and i want "0.0" in DB(means its not updating bean on JS code or event).

this is what element m using_

```
<f:subview id="PaymentRuleView" rendered="#{login.employee}">
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="PaymentRuleForm">
<x:div id="PaymentRuleDiv" styleClass="separateBox">
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="partReminder" onclick="hideText(id)" />
                <h:outputText styleClass="separateMargin" value="For Part Payment" />
                <h:inputText id="partReminderText"
                    value="#{SelectedBean.payment_1_reminder}"
                    size="3">
                </h:inputText>
</x:div>
</h:form>
</f:subview>
```

And this is JS _

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    var txt="PaymentRuleView:PaymentRuleForm:";
    var partTxt="partReminderText";
    var finalTxt="finalReminderText";
    if(document.getElementById(txt+partTxt).value>0)
    {
        document.getElementById(txt+"partReminder").checked=true;
        document.getElementById(txt+partTxt).readOnly = false;          
    }else{
        document.getElementById(txt+"partReminder").checked=false;
        document.getElementById(txt+partTxt).readOnly= true;
        document.getElementById(txt+partTxt).value = 0.0;
    }
    if(document.getElementById(txt+finalTxt).value>0 ){
        document.getElementById(txt+"finalReminder").checked = true;
        document.getElementById(txt+finalTxt).readOnly = false;
    }else{
        document.getElementById(txt+"finalReminder").checked=false;
        document.getElementById(txt+finalTxt).readOnly = true;
        document.getElementById(txt+finalTxt).value = 0.0;
    }
});
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hideText(e) {

        var value = document.getElementById(e).value;
        var textBox;
        if (e.indexOf("partReminder") != -1) {
            textBox = e.replace("partReminder", "partReminderText");
        } else {
            textBox = e.replace("finalReminder", "finalReminderText");
        }
        if (document.getElementById(e).checked!=true) {         
            document.getElementById(textBox).readOnly = true;
            document.getElementById(textBox).value = 0.0;
        }
        if (document.getElementById(e).checked==true) {
            document.getElementById(textBox).readOnly = false;
            document.getElementById(textBox).value = 0.0;
        }

    }
</script>
```

where am going any buddy idea or any suggestion?
thank you.

**Answer**
I missed "immediate=true " attribute in  which helps me to set changed value to beans 
and it looks like this now_

```
<h:inputText id="partReminderText"
                    value="#{SelectedBean.payment_1_reminder}"
                    size="3" immediate="true">
                </h:inputText>
```

Comment: Looks like you're sending the wrong id of your `<h:inputText>`. `onclick="hideText(id)` it should be `onclick="hideText("formId:partReminderText")`.

Comment: hello, am getting right Id too, and its disabling it too with value "0.0" but its not updating bean too..

Comment: Post the relevant JSF and Java code to replicate your specific problem. This includes posting the managed bean code to replicate the problem and its scope.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i think i missed "immediate=true " , n thankx for answering.. :)

Comment: Then please edit it to show your current scenario and future readers could understand your problem. By the way, how are you sending the data to your server, using `<h:commandButton>`? And why is your form `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, are you submitting files in it?

Comment: yes, am uploading file too, and am using <h:commandLink> for process

Comment: Then please, one more time (and hope it would be the last) edit your question to provide an example of your current scenario in order that me and other users could replicate your problem and analyze it to provide an answer. Otherwise, the question can be closed for not being specific at the problem at hand.

Comment: sorry, @LuiggiMendoza , but i need to add working code at the last by mentioning it ?

Comment: No, just code that help us to analyze your problem and replicate it. This is commonly known as [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)